# How to disable ALL Code Analysis in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, code-analysis

I recently updated from an earlier version of VS 2019 (I don't remember which) to version 16.11.5 and now all my C# code is littered with little gray dots (see screenshot), which I think indicates Code Analysis violations. Is there a way to disable all Code Analysis rules for ALL solutions??? I've searched high and low and everything I've found suggests I can only do this on a per-solution or per-project basis, which is infeasible as I have hundreds of solutions.

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/disable-code-analysis?view=vs-2019

Comment: @HansPassant your link is for per-project settings, is it not? I want to disable it globally for all solutions and projects.